# How much time do you spend in JavaScript development ? And what do you do to reduce it?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how much time (in percent) does JavaScript development takes at your work. I work with complex rich-internet applications and i spend most of my time in JavaScript development.

And you: how much time do you you spend in JavaScript development and what do you do to reduce it ?

regards,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spend quite a bit of time in Javascript (and CSS) development, because I believe in not having any postbacks (or fake postbacks with ASP .Net AJAX) at all, but in rich client side experiences that don't use too much bandwidth.  Therefore, I tend to write most of the server interaction by hand instead of using ASP .Net features.

This means a lot of Javascript, but a vastly superior user experience.

To reduce development time, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com).  I repeat, **use jQuery**.

jQuery has saved me and many other people countless hours of development time.  If you need to do something that jQuery can't do out of the box, search for an applicable plugin.  If you aren't using jQuery already, you will be endlessly grateful.  jQuery hides all of the differences in the HTML DOM between browsers, makes animations infinitely easier to implement, and does lots of other useful things too.

Also, use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com); it makes layouts much easier to debug and play with, and makes Javascript much easier to test.

Comment: I'd be careful with any-old jQuery plugin. Almost exclusively, the ones I've tried that aren't core, have had bugs. It's a bit too open, IMHO. And that said, just because you don't 'believe' in 'postbacks', doesn't mean you need to spend a lot of time in JavaScript.

Comment: Good point about the plugins; I actually haven't used all that many.

Comment: Ditto. JQuery is the best Javascript friend you will ever have. It is cross-browser compliant, and most of the browsers have been tested against all mainstream browsers. There are several hundred free plugins that extend functionality of the base library. You can knock out better Javascript in a few minutes with JQuery than you could in a few weeks by hand coding Javascript.

Comment: Slaks, what do you do when a UI JavaScript plugin does not work as expected ?

Comment: Either fix it or replace it.  Which plugin are you having trouble with?

Comment: JQuery UI dialog. When i use a unique container to load many dynamic pages, JQuery UI dialog does not updates title and button labels. Can you suggest anything else ?

Comment: Ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

IE8's JavaScript debugger has been extremely helpful for me.

Edit: It's actually the only reason I ever run IE8!

Answer (score 1):

I don't spend a lot of time at all; I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to do almost all the work, and then I keep things simple such that I avoid do much work elsewhere. So I'll return the entire HTML I wish to render, for ajax calls, instead of building it up client side, and other such things.

I also do a bunch of 'rich' things, but keep it 'workable'. My 'util.js' is at about 800 lines. Possibly extravagent, but it does a bunch of things. I don't spend a significant amount of time on it anymore.

Comment: Hi Silky, what do you do when a UI JavaScript plugin does not work as expected ?

Comment: Stop using it, and write my own.

Answer (score 1):

I did research on the internet first search for a component that i need for my website. if there is none or conflicted with my javascript (i am using jquery) so I will create it by my own. It shouldn't take very long to do that.

thanks to jquery and another javascript library (also firebug) ..they help a lot.

Time to spend for javascript development is about 10-15% of development time.

Answer (score 0):

Next to none.  IMHO, javascript is best kept for client-side form validation (and even then, only as a helper to strict server-side form validation).  Occasionally I use it, but it's best avoided, I think.  Certainly, I wouldn't ever do much in it that didn't use a library like jquery.